# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') I can't use my variable again

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I had confused by this kind of error despite I had used the self variable products to display all my products but when I try to use it again I can't catch it noted that variable I got it by calling Axios by redux. why I didn't know:
so this is my code:

```
import React, {useEffect} from "react";
import Product from "../components/Product";
import LoadingBox from "../components/LoadingBox";
import AlertBox from "../components/AlertBox";
import {useSelector, useDispatch} from "react-redux";
import {listProducts} from "../actions/productAction";



const HomePage = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
   
    useEffect(()=> {
     dispatch(listProducts()); 
     
     }, [dispatch])
     const productsList = useSelector((state) => state.productsList);
    
   const {products, loading, error} = productsList;

console.log(products)
const categories = products.map((x)=> x.subCategory);
console.log(categories)
    return (
 <div>
       
            {loading? (<LoadingBox></LoadingBox>):error? (<AlertBox variant="danger" >{error}</AlertBox>):(
                <div className="row center" >
                 {
                    products.map((product) => (
                     <Product key={product._id} product={product} ></Product>
                    ))}
                    </div>
            )}
                 
            </div>             
    )

};
export default HomePage;
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand you. What is your error? It would be nice if you'd use punctuation marks next time

Comment: i try to extract the category item from the products to use an other time but I ca

Comment: What is getting printed when you log `products`?

Comment: it's print me" Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet you initialize your store `state.productsList` with `null`, thus you have to check if products really fetched or provide default value for `productsList`.

```
const categories = products?.length 
 ? products.map(({subCategory})=> subCategory)
 : [];
```

Comment: you are amazing my friend.thank you so much.i'm so gratefull.

Comment: can you explain me this code "products?.length ".it's the first time I see.

Comment: It's Optional chaining. You can read more about it - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Answer (score 0):

The **map** function is only used to iterate an array. If any other type of data is been sent into products then use the following exception to not produce a crash or error.

Syntax

```
array.map((item, index) => {
  //code
})
```

Your representation

```
<div className="row center" >
   {products?.map((product) => (
       <Product key={product._id} product={product} ></Product>
   ))}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are missing is short circuiting.
When you use redux thunk as a middleware or any asynchronous way to fetch the data from server,then you have to make sure each node of the object which you want to render should be found.
It is because at the very first miliseconds the data is not already fetched but react tends to render the data which will obviously null or undefinded as the data is not fetched yet.

This can be solved in two different ways with short circuiting.

**1. Pass the deepest node or make sure the length of products is not 0 by passing it in a dependency array as:**

```
useEffect(()=> {
     dispatch(listProducts()); 
     
     }, [dispatch,products?.length])
```

**2.**

```
{products?.products.map((product) => (
       <Product key={product._id} product={product} ></Product>
   ))}
```

for more refrerence,you can look at:[short-circuiting-evaluation in javascript](https://medium.com/khojchakra/understanding-short-circuit-evaluation-in-javascript-31b5770a41f7)